# can a ajax source be a http file somewhere else (that is not on the same server)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Excuse my ignorance or my lack of knowledge in ajax.

In relation to this datatables [example](https://datatables.net/beta/1.8/examples/ajax/deep.html) Can the file that feeds the table `"sources/deep.txt"` be a http link e.g. `https://www.dropbox.com/s/380w6wafrecozqg/deep.txt`? or does it have to be a file somewhere in the same server e.g. `../someOther/Directory/nearby/deep.txt`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "sources/deep.txt",
        //would this work?
        //"sAjaxSource": "https://www.dropbox.com/s/380w6wafrecozqg/deep.txt",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "engine" },
            { "mDataProp": "browser" },
            { "mDataProp": "platform.inner" },
            { "mDataProp": "platform.details.0" },
            { "mDataProp": "platform.details.1" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be on another server depending on the circumstances.  This is known as a cross-origin request.

The server you're requesting data from has to allow the request.  It does this via [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).  A typical permissive header will be something like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: so would I have to set something on the other server? and would I write it like this in the ajax request `//"sAjaxSource": "https://www.dropbox.com/s/380w6wafrecozqg/deep.txt",`

Comment: I don't know anything about your dataTable plugin, but yes if `sAjaxSource` is where you specify a URL for a data source, then that's where you'd put your URL with your data.  And, yes the server will need to allow cross-origin loading of the data.  Many services are set up to enable cross-origin GET requests automatically, but many aren't.